# create column with a running total in a Spark Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

Suppose we have a Spark Dataset with two columns, say Index and Value, sorted by the first column (Index).

```
((1, 100), (2, 110), (3, 90), ...)
```

We'd like to have a Dataset with a third column with a running total of the values in the second column (Value).

```
((1, 100, 100), (2, 110, 210), (3, 90, 300), ...)
```

Any suggestions how to do this efficiently, with one pass through the data? Or are there any canned CDF type functions out there that could be utilized for this?

If need be, the Dataset can be converted to a Dataframe or an RDD to accomplish the task, but it will have to remain a distributed data structure. That is, it cannot be simply collected and turned to an array or sequence, and no mutable variables are to be used (`val` only, no `var`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague suggested the following which relies on the [`RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@mapPartitionsWithIndex[U](f:(Int,Iterator[T])=%3EIterator[U],preservesPartitioning:Boolean)(implicitevidence$9:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) method. 
(To my knowledge, the other data structure do not provide this kind of reference to their partitions' indices.)

```
val data = sc.parallelize((1 to 5))  // sc is the SparkContext
val partialSums = data.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (i, values) => 
    Iterator((i, values.sum))
}.collect().toMap  // will in general have size other than data.count
val cumSums = data.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (i, values) => 
    val prevSums = (0 until i).map(partialSums).sum
    values.scanLeft(prevSums)(_+_).drop(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but it will have to remain a distributed data structure.

Unfortunately what you've said you seek to do isn't possible in Spark. If you are willing to repartition the data set to a single partition (in effect consolidating it on a single host) you could easily write a function to do what you wish, keeping the incremented value as a field.

Since Spark functions don't share state across the network when they execute, there's no way to create the shared state you would need to keep the data set completely distributed.

If you're willing to relax your requirement and allow the data to be consolidated and read through in a single pass on one host then you may do what you wish by repartitioning to a single partition and applying a function. This does not pull the data onto the driver (keeping it in HDFS/the cluster) but does still compute the output serially, on a single executor. For example:

```
package com.github.nevernaptitsa

import java.io.Serializable
import java.util

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, SparkSession}

object SparkTest {

  class RunningSum extends Function[Int, Tuple2[Int, Int]] with Serializable {
    private var runningSum = 0
    override def apply(v1: Int): Tuple2[Int, Int] = {
      runningSum+=v1
      return (v1, runningSum)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val session = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("runningSumTest")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    import session.implicits._
    session.createDataset(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))
      .repartition(1)
      .map(new RunningSum)
      .show(5)
    session.createDataset(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))
      .map(new RunningSum)
      .show(5)
  }

}
```

The two statements here show different output, the first providing the correct output (serial, because `repartition(1)` is called), and the second providing incorrect output because the result is computed in parallel.

Results from first statement:

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  6|
|  4| 10|
|  5| 15|
+---+---+
```

Results from second statement:

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  4|
|  5|  9|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, @Ed.  

I suspected as much.  

Perhaps I should look into a [Greenwald-Khanna](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~datar/courses/cs361a/papers/quantiles.pdf) type of approximation approach for this use case.

Comment: No problem @BahmanEngheta ! If you're satisfied with my answer would you mind marking it as accepted?